# Combination without repetition in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, combinations

How could I obtain 48 random pairs of two different elements drawn from `Range[96]` with no repetition ? That is the 96 elements are only used once.

While I tried Tuples/Subsets combined with Select, I feel there must be a more straightforward way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want a random pair ? because `{1,2},{3,4}..{97,98}` is a trivial comb that I could think of ...

Comment: Three minutes late with an identical response.

Comment: @Daniel One of the advantages of the 10k+ status is that you can see this happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please tell me if this is correct:

```
Partition[RandomSample@Range@96, 2]
```

Comment: How about RandomSample@Range@96~Partition~2?

Comment: ...or did the running gag finish its marathon?

Comment: ahahah, I have decided "~" was to dangerous for me yet. I think, in a year maybe :-)

Comment: @500 Well, Mr.Wiz got me thinking about its usage. I will be on the outlook for opportunities where it will improve readability and use it.

Comment: @500 Apparently I am the oddball for using it, so don't be in a hurry to join me.  (I didn't see Sjoerd's comment immediately before this; I guess it's not all bad!)

Comment: And I kept my mouth wide shut

Answer (score 4):

```
Partition[RandomSample[Range[96]],2]
```

Comment: I don't need to compete :) Tried it in mathematica and pasted it here

Comment: Happens all the time. Never mind. Have you been looking around here (Mathematica tag) before?

Comment: Have a look at this when you have time http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3277/2208

Comment: @Sjoerd, What do you think of the above ?

Comment: @500 the code golf? nice code. Mathematica has auto indent though, so I don't know how that would interact. Prashant: you really should check in here more often. You'd like it here.

Comment: @Sjoerd, I only see the auto indent when narrowing the window. Any other mean to do so ?